# Remove PHP extension using .htaccess methods (Keeping Link Juice)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, sef

I'm trying to remove the .php extension on my URLs to make it Search Engine Friendly using the .htaccess file Redirect 301, to keep the "rank juice" and I as much I've tried almost every example around - It just doesn't seem to work.

Here are some of the methods I've unsuccessfully tried already:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

*This is the most common solution given but nothing happens and there is no changes.*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

*Nothing happens and there is no changes.*

```
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
# RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
# RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

*I get a **Not Found** : The requested URL /AMENPTHOME/hostnd/3/9/9/399fc7b78/www/htdocs/web/dive-sites.php was not found on this server.*

Amen is my host and the file dive-sites.php in this specific real example is on the root.
My goal is to have: **www.domain.com/dive-sites** and not **www.domain.com/dive-sites.php** using a Redirect 301 because this url is already ranked for a while. Can someone please help ?

Thank you very much, all help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I didn't missed anything:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(.+)\.php[^\s]* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Requests to `/dive-sites.php` will issue a 301 redirect to `/dive-sites`, appending query-strings if any.

Requests to `/dive-sites` will get a 200 response with `/dive-sites.php` as `Content-Location`, appending query-strings if any.

Comment: like a charm! would never get this.

Comment: @pedroteixeira07 I'm glad that I was able to help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^/(.+)(($|#)*(.*)) /$1.php$2

If removing only the .php this will work.

$1 = for the name of the page, e.g **foo**

$2 = take note of the hashtag or the get request

eg.


*<domain>/example ----> <domain>/example.php

<domain>/example?get=this ----> <domain>/example.php?get=this

<domain>/example#hash ----> <domain>/example.php#hash*

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for `.php` extension removal:

```
RewriteEngine On

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: I guess the external redirect is working nicelly since it does remove the extension but as for the internally forward I'm still getting:   404 Not Found The requested URL /services was not found on this server. (in this case for the file services.php)

Comment: What was the original URL? Is this placed in DOCUMENT_ROOT or some other subdir?

Comment: Although trough Filezilla they are in the folder /public/www - I'm assuming this is the root since the original files are in the folder www in the same location as index.php. For example: www.domain.com/service.php

Comment: Exactly. More precisely: The requested URL /service was not found on this server.