# Removing .php extention and adding a / at the end

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I removed my .php extension with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This works I can access my site like this: **www.example.com/page**
Now I have got the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This works too, well kind off. I was testing it out in a sub-folder and now comes the problem:

when I go to **www.example.com/sub/page** it goes to **www.example.com/page/** and there it say's that the *folder* page isn't found!

Does anyone has a solution?

Comment: Duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751890/php-htaccess-removing-php-extension-from-url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963638/htaccess-remove-url-extension-add-trailing-slash
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337695/remove-php-extension-with-php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540353/using-htaccess-to-remove-php-file-extension-from-url

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904911/remove-php-extension-using-htaccess-methods-keeping-link-juice
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much anubhava! This worked indeed! But is it normal that the css doesn't get loaded when I use this methode?

Comment: Glad to know it worked out. For CSS/JS you should just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.